# One-to-one relationship does not carry both classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using the Entity Framework to persist and retrieve some information, I have a one-to-one relationship.
Product and Category, where a Product has a Category and a Category may have several Products.

I have the following structure

I created the two entities and made the relationship, but when I retrieve this information it brings me the information of the products however the category comes as null

Produto.cs

```
public class Produto 
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public string observacao { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public decimal valorVenda { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria categoria { get; set; }
}
```

Categoria.cs

```
public class Categoria 
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("categoriaid")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public string observacao { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public virtual Produto produto { get; set; }
}
```

ProdutoContexto.cs

```
public class ProdutoContexto : DbContext 
{
    public ProdutoContexto(DbContextOptions<ProdutoContexto> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Produto>()
            .HasOne(a => a.categoria)
            .WithOne(b => b.produto)
            .HasForeignKey<Categoria>(b => b.id);
    }

    public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}
```

CategoriaContexto.cs

```
public class CategoriaContexto : DbContext 
{
    public CategoriaContexto(DbContextOptions<CategoriaContexto> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the function to retrieve the information the following json is returned

```
[{"id":1,"descricao":"Coca-Cola","observacao":"Coca-Cola Gelada","status":1,"valorVenda":5.50,"categoria":null}]
```

My Query is:

```
[HttpGet] 
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Produto>>> GetProdutos() 
{ 
   return await _context.Produtos.ToListAsync(); 
}
```

Note that the category is null, how can it be done in such a way that the category is already loaded?

Comment: " a Category may have several Products." That is **not** a one-to-one relationship, but a one-to-many relationship. You may want to model it as such, because a one-to-one relationship makes absolutely no sense in this case.

Comment: Firstly, it's not 1:1 as you say but it's actually 1 to many. Secondly, you're not setting the relationship correctly. Please search online how to create one to many in EF. Even online examples are mostly about product and category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Category may have several Products.

Then its not `one-to-one`, instead its `one-to-many` and your model classes should be as follows:

```
public class Categoria 
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public string observacao { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Produto> produtos { get; set; }
}

public class Produto 
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("categoria")]
    public int categoriaId {get; set;}

    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public string observacao { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public decimal valorVenda { get; set; }

    public virtual Categoria categoria { get; set; }
}
```

And you don't need any `FluentAPI` configuration. So remove the `modelBuilder.Entity<Produto>()` configuration. And you also don't need two different DbContext for `Produto` and `Categoria` separately. Instead make your `DbContext` as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContexto : DbContext 
{
    public ApplicationDbContexto(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContexto> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}
```

And your query should be as follows:

```
[HttpGet] 
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Produto>>> GetProdutos() 
{ 
   return await _context.Produtos.Include(p => p.categoria).ToListAsync(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I followed your example and even when I retrieve a product my category comes as null, should I implement anything else to also load the category?

Comment: @EmiryMirella This is because your `Produtos` and `Categorias` are in two different `DbContext`. See my updated answer and take a look at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: The problem continues, even though I add everything in one context

Comment: @EmiryMirella Add your query to the question that you are trying. Morover is it an ASP.NET Core project or ASP.NET MVC  project?

Comment: a web api in .net core

Comment: my callback  [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Produto>>> GetProdutos()
        {
            return await _context.Produtos.ToListAsync();
        }

Comment: @EmiryMirella See my updated answer and take a look at the bottom of my answer.